# C/C++ : double constants in class are inaccurate

Tags: c++, double, constants

I'm writing a class in C++ that needs some constants that are accessible throughout the whole class. Normally I would use a #define, a const- or a static declaration but there is something strange happening: 
So for example I write

`#define Rm 8.3144621`

but `std::cout << Rm << std::endl;`

prints 8.31446.

I also tried

```
#define Rm 831.44621e-2
```

and `const double Rm = 8.3144621`

and  `static double Rm = 8.3144621`

and every possible way to initialize or cast to a double constant.

Is there a solution for that or do I have to use fields?

Comment: You're just not printing them with enough precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to output the double with all digits, you need to set correct precision:

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << Rm << std::endl;
```

See a live demo here: [Double print Demo](http://ideone.com/vnpqTi)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << Rm << std::endl
```